# how to connect a react component from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying connect my components to a page.
I do this.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/react-dom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/views/item.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="/js/views/list.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<List url="/get"/>, document.getElementById("content")) ;
</script>
```

But i am getting an error Uncaught ReferenceError: List is not defined
How can i fix it?

Comment: Use a module management system, like webpack, instead of global variables. If you want to piss in the eye of good practice then in in the list file do `window.List = ....`

Comment: You are not importing Link anywhere in your page that the App knows what it is. What you are showing is not proper pattern design.